# Display unix timestamp in human friendly format

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

I am experimenting with building forms with [Alpaca.js](http://www.alpacajs.org). I am storing my dates as unix timestamps but I would like them to be displayed to the user in another (any other!) format.

```
$("#field").alpaca({
    // data is a unix timestamp
    "data": "1423785600000",
    "options": {
        "type": "date",
        "dateFormat": "DD/MM/YYYY" // expecting it to be converted to this format for display
    }
});
```

"dateFormat" sounds like it might be the right thing but its not clear to me from the reading I have done.

Is this possible with Alpaca? Am I just doing it wrong?

I have a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/np5ua7xL/2/

Ideally when the form is submitted the date would be turned back into a unix timestamp, but I can take care of that on the server if need be.